# Database in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

We put the program on the joomla article and we have the config.php located in the directory/images/php/config.php

I have 2 php pages that i want to include in joomla (pond.php and p_pond.php)
pond.php has a submit button, but when the submit button is clicked, it does not connect to database and it does not go to p_pond.php page

How can we connect to the database when the page is loaded?

Comment: Would you expand your question more?  Not quite sure what that first paragraph means.

Comment: Maybe your question is just worded oddly, but I think you have far misunderstood how Joomla works.  You don't code your own php files/pages; Joomla takes care of most of that.  Your questions can be interpreted a lot of ways, most all of which show a misunderstanding of how Joomla works.

Comment: why didn't you make a basic module and embed them in the article? Means you have the framework to back you up, make life easier rather than having a completely separate script.

Answer (score 0):

Use JUMI component to use your personal PHP page and look at this [page for database connection](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script#Tips.2C_Tricks_.26_FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla works on MVC so you should follow the MVC rule.
For displaying a page you need to make a component. 
read joomla docs to make component 
here is the link http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/1.5/Introduction